# Use of Stokes theorem

Tags: calculus

I'm unsure of how to calculate this integral using Stokes' theorem. 
$$\iint_S \left( \nabla \times \mathbf{F} \right) \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}$$ 
where $S$ is the surface of a sphere defined by 
$$
S = \left\{(x,y,z) \ | \ x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1 \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ x+y+z\geq 1\right\}
$$
and 
$$
\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{r} \times \left(\mathbf{i} + \mathbf{j} + \mathbf{k}\right) \ \ \ \text{   where   } \ \ \  \mathbf{r} = x\mathbf{i} + y\mathbf{j} + z\mathbf{k}
$$

Could you please help?

Answer (score 2):

Stokes' theorem states for sufficient conditions on $\mathbf{F}$ and $S$,
$$
\iint_S \nabla \times \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{S} \equiv \int_{\partial S} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{s}.
$$
This theorem is extremely powerful in that it relates the integral over a body's surface to the integral over the body's boundary. We're implicitly talking about bodies existing in $\mathbb{R^3}$ here due to the nature of the cross product. It says if you have a closed-loop boundary $\partial S$, then the circulation of a vector field through *any* surface $S$ that has that closed-loop boundary is independent of the surface itself. Applying the cross product directly, we see
$$
\mathbf{F} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{pmatrix}
\times
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
y - z \\
z - x \\
x - y
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Also, we know a region on the sphere exists such that $x + y + z \geq 1$ since a circular arc is traced in the first quadrant of the $x$-$y$ plane and there is a point at $(0,0,1)$ that trivially satisfies both conditions. Since both the sphere and the constraint are smooth, there is a smooth surface connecting $(0,0,1)$ to the 
circular arc. For these reasons, we choose the positive $z$ branch. $S$ is shown below where the orange surface is part of the sphere and the blue surface is the plane. The intersection of the two is this curve we're looking for that joins the circular arc with the point $(0,0,1)$.

$\hskip 1.5 in$[image: S]

This curve is given implicitly by
$$
1 - x - y - \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2} = 0.
$$
Since we're intersecting a sphere with a plane, then we know this curve is circular in $\mathbb{R^3}$ but elliptic in the $x$-$y$ plane after projection. So finding results about it in one variable actually determines results for the other variable immediately due to symmetry if one needed to express results differently. We need to know the bounds of the curve in the $x$-$y$ plane. If we denote this function as $f$, then we know
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = -\frac{f_x}{f_y} = - \frac{\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2} - x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2} - y}.
$$
Equating to zero, we find
$$
x = \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2} \implies x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1-y^2}{2}},
$$
but $x + y + z \geq 1$ so we must take the positive branch again since the plane cuts mostly in the first octant because of the way it's oriented. Now the value of $y$ that minimizes $f$ in the $x$-$y$ plane is known by
$$
f\left(\sqrt{\frac{1 - y^2}{2}}, y\right) = 1 - y - \sqrt{2-2y^2} = 0 \implies y = \left\{-\frac{1}{3},1\right\}.
$$
But if $y = 1$, then
$$
f(x,1) = -\frac{\sqrt{-x^2} - x}{\sqrt{-x^2} - 1},
$$
and $f,x$ are real, a contradiction. So $y = -1/3$. Regardless, we know the bounds of $y$ (and also $x$) for the ellipse to be $y \in (-1/3,1)$. Now we know what we needed for both the circular curve and the elliptic curve. We do need to be careful, though, and use the provided symmetry to switch our results from $y$ to $x$ since the elliptic curve is multivalued in $y(x)$ for $x \in (-1/3,0)$ and likewise for $x(y)$ with $y \in (-1/3,0)$.

$\hskip 1.5 in$[image: elliptic and circular arc in plane]

$$
\text{circle}
\begin{cases}
x \in (0,1) \\
y = \sqrt{1 - x^2} \\
z = 0
\end{cases}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{ellipse}
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{1 - y - \sqrt{(2-3y)y + 1}}{2} & y \in (0,1) \\
y &= \frac{1 - x - \sqrt{(2-3x)x + 1}}{2} & x \in (0,1) \\
z &= 1 - x - y
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

So we finally can use Stokes' theorem. If we let $\Gamma$ be the integral in question, then
\begin{align}
\Gamma &= \int_{\partial S} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{s} \\
&= \int_\text{circ}
\begin{pmatrix}
y - z \\
z - x \\
x - y
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathrm{d}x \\
\mathrm{d}y \\
\mathrm{d}z \\
\end{pmatrix}
 +
\int_\text{ellip}
\begin{pmatrix}
y - z \\
z - x \\
x - y
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathrm{d}x \\
\mathrm{d}y \\
\mathrm{d}z \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Note particularly for the elliptical part that
$$
\mathrm{d}x = x'(y) \, \mathrm{d}y, \ \ \ \mathrm{d}y = y'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x, \ \ \ \mathrm{d}z = z'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \ \ \ \text{or} \ \ \ \mathrm{d}z = z'(y) \, \mathrm{d}y,
$$
where for $z$, using $y = y(x)$ or $x = x(y)$ and then taking the derivative is understood.

Does that help? See if you can finish.

---

You can think of a sphere (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) as being made up of infinitely many circles (in some oriented $\mathbb{R}^2$) stacked on top of each other starting from a point (a circle with zero radius) and infinitesimally increasing in radius until the sphere's radius has been reached. This structure so far is called a hemisphere, and the sphere is completed by just gluing another hemisphere on top. Notice that I've said nothing about the orientation of these rings making up the sphere.

Now we take a plane (a surface just like $\mathbb{R}^2$ but oriented a little differently) and introduce it into the same space as the sphere. Only 1 of 3 possibilities happens.

1. The plane does not intersect the sphere (no solutions).
2. The plane intersects the sphere at a single point (one solution).
3. The plane intersects the sphere and their intersection traces out one of the circles used to construct the sphere (family of solutions).

The sphere is represented as $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and the plane that represents the boundary of the region $x + y + z \geq 1$ is $x + y + z = 1$. The surface $S$ is shown below (red) satisfying both $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ (white) and $x + y + z \geq 1$ (grey). The boundary $\partial S$ is the circle formed by the edge of $S$.

$\hskip 1.3 in$[image: surface view 1]

$\hskip 1.5 in$[image: surface view 2]

Truthfully I only gave half of the picture before by stopping at the $x$-$y$ plane. But I did botch the wording about $\Gamma$ which was misleading, and that's on my part, so my apologies for that.

So $\partial S$ is a circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If we can figure out how to trace it parametrically, then (for real this time) $\Gamma$ is known. We have 2 options.

1. Do the top hemisphere ($z > 0$) first and then the lower hemisphere ($z < 0$), equating each with the plane.
2. Do both hemispheres at the same time by equating $z^2$ with $z^2$ ($z^2 - z^2 = 0$).

Option 2 is slightly faster.
$$
1 - x^2 - y^2 - (1 - x - y)^2 = 0
$$
you should see familiar equations solving for $x(y)$ and $y(x)$. These are equations for $\partial S$ projected downwards onto the $x$-$y$ plane, so if you can write explicitly $y(x)$ $($or $x(y))$ and find bounds on $x$ (or $y$), then you can integrate along $\partial S$ as a normal line integral in $x$ (or $y$). You can include the integral over the circle in the $x$-$y$ plane if you want to, but it's very unnecessary since it will cancel.

Comment: I don't undertand

Comment: Where do you start to have trouble?

Comment: I have problems when I have to find where the sphere and the plane are cut